# Install Twisted on CentOS 5.5

Tags: installation, python, centos5, twisted

CentOS 5.5 is using the old python 2.4 ! But I want to install Twisted on it ! Does anyone maintain a RPM of this library ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twisted is in [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) as the `python-twisted-*` packages.